# Customising Swiper.js Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I've built a simple slider using swiper.js here:

http://advancedflightnz.flywheelsites.com/Swiperjs/Slider.html

As you can see, the 'wrapper' of the progress bar has rounded edges, but the highlighted internal bar doesn't.

I've worked through every css workaround I can think of, but I've come up with nothing, hopefully someone smarter than me has been here before.

Thank you :)

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden;` on the external bar

Comment: Have you tried placing your own `<style>` tag after loading the `css` file for this plugin? You could add `.swiper-pagination-progressbar-fill{border-radius:20px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not very visible but if you really want it, Override the below in css

```
.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-progressbar, .swiper-container-vertical > .swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite {
border-radius : 0 !important;
}
```